# C# Removing list object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application where I have a coin fountain. Every 10 milliseconds a     `coin[i]` is added to a `list` called `coins`. These coins generate with an animation that finds the coin with this for statement `for (int i = 0; i < coins.Count; i++)`. To remove the object I call:

```
if (coins[i].Top > 550)
{
    coins.RemoveAt(i);
    canvas.Children.Remove(coin[i]);
}
```

(*top* is part of a class that sets the top position using margin).

However, when using the `coins.RemoveAt(i);` the list number gets removed as well, so all other items in the list number will be moved down to close the "gap". Is there any way to stop it from filling the "gap", when removing the item?

Comment: And array.  And I would canvas.Children.Remove  first.

Comment: I think the answer to this is to just call canvas.Children.Remove(coin[I]) first, as @Paparazzi seems to be saying.

Comment: With the for loop start index at the max of the list. Then run the loop counting down. Then you can remove the indexes and it will be fine when removing one.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the For loop with the code below. This will find all of the coins with a Top property > 550 then iterate over them removing them from the coins list and the canvas.Children collection.

```
var coinsToRemove = coins.Where(coin => coin.Top > 550);

foreach (var coin in coinsToRemove)
{
    coins.Remove(coin);
    canvas.Children.Remove(coin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

coins.Insert(i, new coin()); is the extra line of code I believe will solve your "filling the gap" problem. My solution is to fill the gap with an empty object.
See My test case below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        class b 
        {
            public int i;
            public b(int x) { i = x; } //Constructor which instantiates objects with respective properties
            public b() { }             //Constructor for empty object to fill gap
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<b> integers = new List<b>(); //List of objects
            integers.Add(new b(5));           //Add some items
            integers.Add(new b(6));
            integers.Add(new b(7));
            integers.Add(new b(8));

            for (int i = 0; i < integers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(integers[i].i); //Do something with the items
            }

            integers.RemoveAt(1);                 //Remove the item at a specific index
            integers.Insert(1, new b());          //Fill the gap at the index of the remove with empty object
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.Count; i++)    //Do the same something with the items
            {
                Console.WriteLine(integers[i].i);       //See that The object that fills the gap is empty
            }
            Console.ReadLine();                     //Wait for user input I.E. using a debugger for test
        }
    }
}
```